# Grab `this` from caller function object

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have [some code](https://github.com/rackerlabs/snappit-mocha-protractor/blob/2fa07f0507d1d697b2d5fc14a051ddff92a9f3fa/test/spec.js#L9) that I'm currently invoking everywhere like this.

```
screenshot.snap(this, $('.navbar-inner .container'));
```

In the above code, the `this` object being passed in is from mocha.js. It contains information like the current test name, the file it's in, etc. I use that information to name the screenshot.

I want to remove the need to pass in the `this` reference everywhere, but no matter how I try to reach up to it inside of the `snap` function, I am unable to find the information I need.

```
var testContext = exports.snap.caller; //.prototype? .this?
```

I have inspected `exports.snap.caller.toString()`, and it is the function called in the mocha test suite. I did this through a debugging repl, and on further inspection see that the only information I can get is [the properties of a function instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), which contains nothing from the calling function's `this`.

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck passing in the `this` argument every time I call my `screenshot.snap` function?

Comment: did you try arguments.callee.caller ?

Comment: [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller#Description): *This property replaces the obsolete arguments.caller property of the arguments object.*...but I also tried `arguments.callee.caller`, it's just a function instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something in the `before` block like:

```
var snap;
before(function () {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');
    snap = screenshot.snap.bind(this);
});
```

And then replace your use of `screenshot.snap(this, $('.navbar-inner .container'));` with `snap($('.navbar-inner .container');`

Depending on how the `this` pointer is handled by mocha, you may need to do that in a `beforeEach` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `this` value of other scopes cannot by programmatically accessed.

You will either need to pass the values explicitly to that `snap` function, or make it available in a global scope that is accessed by the `snap` function.